# Is it possible to have an Xcode built cocoa application output a Unix executable file?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, unix, command-line-interface

I have a simple CLI tool (the product of which is a Unix executable file) that I have built that I would like to make customizable via an OS X app. Would it be possible for me to allow the user to configure some settings in the OS X app, and then allow them to save that configuration into what would be output as my CLI tool?

I am wondering if I can get some advisement on how to merge these two different types of projects.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want the UNIX executable to be _modified/generated_ by your Cocoa program?

Comment: Yes. That is what I am trying to get at. A unix executable that is built according to the custom input from the cocoa app.

Comment: This means you need to bundle a compiler, your source code or pre-compiled object files and the source code you want to modify, and all supporting system files with your Cocoa application. It might be a lot simpler to generate a configuration file that your executable will be able to read or something like that.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can use a scripting language instead of a compiled language, you could do it simply enough.

Comment: Just to be clear, by "Unix executable file", you mean a compiled C application, not an interpreted script? If the latter, the solution is much easier.

Comment: @zneak it looks like your config file route is quite a viable option. I am going to go down that path and see where I get. Thanks!